# Can I make the camera follow me outside of battle?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In most games, the camera automatically follows the direction your character is facing only by moving the left stick. Final Fantasy XV doesn't.

I mean, if the camera is pointed at a given direction outside of a battle, it will continue to do so indefinitely, and I need to use the right stick to move it. Problems start to appear when I also want to run, which is true for 95% of the time. Then I have to hold circle (or square in Control type B) AND move the right stick at the same time. That becomes a problem when I only have one thumb on my right hand.

Am I missing something? Is there an option somewhere to make the camera automatically follow?

Thanks.

Comment: So what you're saying is you need a special way to make the camera follow you because the three ways you can do it are not to your liking...

Comment: Pressing L3 to sprint is pretty common. It took me some getting used to the first time I played a game with it, but it's second nature to me now. Maybe it will become less awkward if you use it more? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to keep the camera centered behind you at all times out of battle.

You can press the lock on button (**R1** on controller types A and B) to center the camera behind you while exploring, though you will have to adjust the direction of the left stick to run with the camera.

Comment: Awesome, that really helps because I can hold square to run and center the camera at the same time. Thanks!